# Why are local models of blow-ups compatible by gluing with transition functions in the normal bundle?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, submanifold, blowup

I am trying to understand the blow-up along a submanifold as explained in Huybrechts "Complex Geometry An Introduction", p. 99, Example 2.5.2.

For background, for $m \leq n$, we see $\mathbb C^m \subset \mathbb C^n$ as $\{ z_{m+1} = \ldots = z_n = 0 \}$ and define
$$
Bl_{\mathbb C^m} (\mathbb C^n) := \{ (x,z): z_i x_j = z_j x_i, \forall i, j = m+1, \ldots, n \}
\subset \mathbb P^{n-m-1} \times \mathbb C^n
$$

Let $U, V \mathbb C^n$ be two open sets and with a biholomorphic map $\phi: U \rightarrow V$ with $\phi(U \cap \mathbb C^m) = V \cap \mathbb C^m$.
I am trying to understand Huybrechts' explanation of how to glue together
$Bl_{\mathbb C^m \cap U} (U)$ and $Bl_{\mathbb C^m \cap V}(V)$ using $\phi$.

Firstly, writing the coordinate in $U$ as $z=(z_1, \ldots, z_n)$ and $\phi=(\phi^1, \ldots, \phi^n)$, he defines the complex numbers $\phi_{k,j}$ by the equation
$$
\phi^k = \sum_{j=m+1}^n z_j \phi_{k,j}
$$
This seems a bit nonsensical to me, as $\phi^k$ is simply a function of $z$, it's not necessarily linear in $z$. But what I think he means in fact is this: if we write $z_i' := \phi^i(z)$, then:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial z_k'} = \sum_{j=m+1}^n \frac{\partial \phi^k}{\partial z_j} \frac{\partial}{\partial z_j}
$$
so then $\phi_{k,j} = \frac{\partial \phi^k}{\partial z_j}$ in fact.
Now he says that the map $\hat \phi: \mathbb P^{n-m-1} \times (\mathbb C^n \cap U) \rightarrow \mathbb  P^{n-m-1} \times (\mathbb C^n \cap V)$ given by:
$$
\hat\phi(x,z) := ((\phi_{k,j}(z))_{k,j=m+1,\ldots, n} \cdot x, \phi(z))
$$
defines a map $\hat\phi: Bl_{\mathbb C^m \cap U} (U) \rightarrow Bl_{\mathbb C^m \cap V} (V)$ when restricted to $Bl_{\mathbb C^m \cap U} (U)$.

**I don't understand why** $\hat\phi(Bl_{\mathbb C^m \cap U} (U)) \subset Bl_{\mathbb C^m \cap V} (V)$.

Indeed, the inclusion would mean that if $z_i x_k = z_k x_i$ for $i,k = m+1, \ldots, n$, then:
$$
\phi^i(z) \sum_{j={m+1}}^n \frac{\partial \phi^k}{\partial z_j}(z) x_j = 
\phi^k(z) \sum_{j={m+1}}^n \frac{\partial \phi^i}{\partial z_j}(z) x_j
$$

As it stands, this condition seems blatantly false!

So what am I getting wrong here? Maybe this is not the condition that needs to be checked? But then how are $Bl_{\mathbb C^m \cap U} (U)$ and $Bl_{\mathbb C^m \cap V}(V)$ glued using $\phi$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, in the equations for $k\geq m+1$,
$$
\phi^k(z) = \sum_{j=m+1}^n z_j \phi_{k,j}(z), \tag{1}
$$
the author didn't mean that $\phi_{k, j}(z)$ are numbers. (His omitting $(z)$ seems to be the source of the confusion.) They are actually functions of $(z_1,\dots,z_n)$, and their existence is guaranteed by the condition that $\phi(U\cap {\mathbb C}^m) = V\cap {\mathbb C}^m$. Basically, when $z_j=0$ for all $j\geq m+1$ we have $\phi^k=0$ for all $k\geq m+1$, so we have such a form. (See also the proof of him 2.4.7.)

The $\phi_{k,j}$ are different from your linearized version $\frac{\partial \phi^k}{\partial z_j}$, although they are the same on $U\cap {\mathbb C}^m$, where $z_{m+1}=\dots=z_n=0$. For we can differentiate (1) to see
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial \phi^k}{\partial z_j} &= \frac{\partial}{\partial z_j}\Big(\sum_{l=m+1}^n  \phi_{k,l}(z) z_l\Big)\\
&= \phi_{k, j}(z) + \sum_{l=m+1}^n  \frac{\partial \phi_{k,l}}{\partial z_j} z_l.
\end{align*}
Therefore, on $U\cap {\mathbb C}^m$ when $z_{m+1}=\dots=z_n=0$,
we have
$$
\frac{\partial \phi^k}{\partial z_j}(z) =\phi_{k, j}(z).
$$

Then the condition you proposed to check is totally right. That is, if
$$
z_ix_k = z_kx_i\tag{2}
$$ for $i, k=m+1,\dots,n$, we should have
$$
\phi^i(z)\sum_{j=m+1}^n  \phi_{k,j}(z)x_j = \phi^k(z)\sum_{j=m+1}^n \phi_{i,j}(z)x_j.
$$

The proof is simply plugging in the equation (1) and use the incidence relation (2).
\begin{align*}
\phi^i(z)\sum_{j=m+1}^n  \phi_{k,j}(z)x_j &\overset{(1)}{=} \sum_{l=m+1}^n \phi_{i, l}(z)z_l \sum_{j=m+1}^n  \phi_{k,j}(z)x_j\\
&=\sum_{j,l=m+1}^n \phi_{i, l}(z) \phi_{k,j}(z) z_l x_j\\
&\overset{(2)}=\sum_{j,l=m+1}^n \phi_{i, l}(z) \phi_{k,j}(z) z_j x_l\\
&=\sum_{j=m+1}^n  \phi_{k,j}(z)z_j \sum_{l=m+1}^n \phi_{i, l}(z)x_l\\
&\overset{(1)}{=}\phi^k(z) \sum_{j=m+1}^n  \phi_{i,j}(z)x_j.
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you! I understand your answer fully and it answers my question. I know it escapes the scope of my initial question, but my goal was to understand why we can see the exceptional divisor set as the projectivisation of the normal bundle, this is why I (wrongly) assumed that $\phi_{k,j} = \frac{\partial \phi^k}{\partial z_j}$. If you can, could you please also explain how the $\phi_{k,j}$ relate to the normal bundle? The author says that "over $\mathbb C^m$, $\phi_{i,j}$ are by definition the cocycle of the normal bundle". This is an essential part of what I was trying to get.

Comment: I can edit the question if need be.

Comment: I don't think it is hard to see this, at least intuitively. The cocycle is just the transition functions for local coordinates of the normal bundle. In the new chart, the coordinates of the normal bundle is $(\phi^{m+1},\dots,\phi^n)$, and in the original chart, it is $(z_{m+1},\dots,z_n)$. Therefore the matrix relating them is the transition function (from the old to the new in this case $\phi(U\cap C^m) = V\cap C^m$.)

Comment: Also $\phi_{k, j} = \frac{\partial \phi^k}{\partial z_j}$ on $C^m$ where $z_{m+1}=\dots=z_n=0$ (as can be checked by product rule). So your formula is not far off, and at $C^m$, they too can serve as cocycles for the normal bundle at the submanifold.

Comment: But why $\phi_{k, j} = \frac{\partial \phi^k}{\partial z_j}$ on $\mathbb C^m$? This is what I fail to see.

Comment: I edited the part in the post about this.

Comment: I am truly thankful, you cleared up a point of confusion which has been lingering for a long time with me.